# Getting Connections of a person by id in LinkedIn

Tags: java, linkedin-api, linkedin-j

I need to get the connections of a user whose id is yZTcaxINNv. I use linkedin-j and the code looks something like this

```
import com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.LinkedInApiClient;
import com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.LinkedInApiClientFactory;
import com.google.code.linkedinapi.schema.Connections;
import com.google.code.linkedinapi.schema.Person;


public class Linkedin_Data_Extract {



public static void main(String[] args) {
       final String consumerKeyValue = "My key";
        final String consumerSecretValue ="My Secret";
        final String accessTokenValue = "Access Token";
        final String tokenSecretValue = "Secret";
        final String id = "yZTcaxINNv";


    final LinkedInApiClientFactory factory = LinkedInApiClientFactory.newInstance(consumerKeyValue, consumerSecretValue);
    final LinkedInApiClient client = factory.createLinkedInApiClient(accessTokenValue, tokenSecretValue);


    Connections cc=client.getConnectionsById(id);

    for(Person p :cc.getPersonList()) {
        System.out.println(p.getLastName());
        System.out.println(p.getId());
        System.out.println("Industry      "+p.getIndustry());
        System.out.println("currentStatus "+p.getCurrentStatus());
        System.out.println("link          "+p.getPublicProfileUrl());
        System.out.println("position      "+p.getEducations());
        System.out.println();
    }
    }
}
```

But i get an error like this

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.LinkedInApiClientException: Access to connections denied
at com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.impl.BaseLinkedInApiClient.createLinkedInApiClientException(BaseLinkedInApiClient.java:3906)
at com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.impl.BaseLinkedInApiClient.callApiMethod(BaseLinkedInApiClient.java:3781)
at com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.impl.BaseLinkedInApiClient.callApiMethod(BaseLinkedInApiClient.java:3725)
at com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.impl.BaseLinkedInApiClient.getConnectionsById(BaseLinkedInApiClient.java:235)
at Linkedin_Data_Extract.main(Linkedin_Data_Extract.java:27)
```

Why am i getting permission issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Third-party APIs that access other users information through OAuth need to be explicitly allowed permission by the user himself.

Normally, this happens through a popup window where the user is asked to allow/reject your app to operate on his data. I'm guessing this is where your issue comes from.

I don't know how linkedin-j does this, but in case you are up for alternatives, you could give [Spring Social](http://projects.spring.io/spring-social-linkedin/) a try, which has a module addressed specifically for Linkedin. See the Quickstart sample in the page I gave you if you're curious

Comment: Agreed. Nice Link. But i want to know the error that i might have done

Comment: Like I said, the user needs to authorize your app, which results in an access token which would normally allow you to access those resources. Where do you get your current access token from?